# check if a number is decimal or integer in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, integer, numbers

I would like to know how I can identify a number as decimal or integer, I was already researching how to do it but I run into some problems when using it in an if else conditional, it gives me the following error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Float' and 'Int'.
```

When requesting the data from the user, I save it as Float and when placing it in the conditional it generates that error. Does anyone know how I can request a number and then check if it is integer or has decimal? By the way I am using kotlin

Code:

```
fun main(){
 val number01 = readLine()!!.toFloat()

 if (number01 % 1 == 0){ // A X + B = 0
        println("Solution 1: $number01")
    }else{
        println("Solution 2: $number01")
    } 
}
```

I already looked on the internet how to know if it is an integer or if it is a number with decimal but when using it in a conditional it generates an error.

Comment: i think you can make use of toFloatOrNull, toIntOrNull, etc to check data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the output from `number01%1` is Float and your using `==` to a Int
.To correct that you have to change your code into:

```
fun main(){
 val number01 = readLine()!!.toFloat()

 if (number01 % 1 == 0f){ 
        println("Solution 1: $number01")
    }else{
        println("Solution 2: $number01")
    } 
}
```